# Swift 3 - Ambiguous use of < operator when comparing two dates

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, swift3

When comparing two Dates in swift, I can compare using >, but not <. 
startTime, endTime and Date() are all of type Date (previously NSDate)

```
   //Broken Code
   if Date() >= startTime && Date() < endTime
   {
       ...
   }
   Gives ambiguous use of < operator error

  //Working Code
   if Date() >= startTime && endTime > Date()
   {
       ...
   }
```

Is there a specific reason this isn't working?

I actually found this example when trying to find the apple documentation, and they actually use this code 
http://www.globalnerdy.com/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-dates-and-times-in-swift-3-part-3-date-arithmetic/

I started wondering if maybe it was the using of the && operator, or possibly just being an issue of the order, but even doing the code by itself as

```
if startTime < endTime {...}
```

But it returns the same order.

Obviously I have found the workaround, But I am very curious why this is happening.

Comment: try `if (Date() >= startTime) && (Date() < endTime) {`

Comment: @LeoDabus I should have put this in the code above, I actually did try that, acted like it wanted to work, and then after maybe 10-12 seconds the compiler came back and gave the same error. Another thing I tried was casting each specifically as a Date, I saw that elsewhere on SO.

Comment: try cleaning your project. both should work

Comment: I suspect you have extended NSDate to conform to comparable protocol,  which it is not needed for Date (Swift 3)

Comment: @LeoDabus I thought I commented that out! Thanks a ton, I am fixing all the errors from going to swift 3, and came across these before the error in the extension.

Comment: @LeoDabus feel free to put that as an answer, And ill accept it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have probably extended `NSDate` to conform to comparable protocol in Swift 2. Just remove it because `Date` now  conforms to Comparable protocol in Swift3.

Comment: When some random dude from the Internet knows my code better than I do…

Comment: The exact same scenario here: two Dates compared;  < complains about being ambiguous, while > works. Indeed, NSDate was previously extended and made to adhere to Comparable (by whoever wrote the Swift2.x version of the app) and the < operator was overwritten. JUST the < operator :-) Leo Dabus, how on earth did you know ??? :-)

Comment: It took me a while to figure out, but I had the following code from Swift 2 which I needed to REMOVE. 

static public func <(a: Date, b: Date) -> Bool {
  return a.compare(b) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
 }