# Swift 3 Why can't Binary operator '===' be applied to two 'Date' operands?

Tags: swift3

```
public func ==(lhs: Date, rhs: Date) -> Bool {
  return lhs === rhs || lhs.compare(rhs) == .orderedSame
}
```

After upgrading to Swift 3 I now get this error... "Binary operator `===`cannot be applied to two `Date` operands"

Any suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Swift 3 Date is a Struct that already conforms to Comparable protocol. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541879/swift-3-ambiguous-use-of-operator-when-comparing-two-dates/39541975#39541975

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift 3 [`Date`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date) is a structure (value type), there is no identities and thus cannot be `===`'ed.

In fact, the `Date` type already provides [a built-in `==`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date/2293580) so you don't need to implement it yourself.

Comment: *there is no identities* what does that mean?

Comment: @Honey Identity = Reference = Pointer value. Structures having the same values are indistinguishable from each other, i.e. you cannot assign identities to each struct value. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25334176/224671.

Answer (score 1):

Dummy code snippet for future reference. Main part is use `timeIntervalSinceNow` that will convert to `Double` and then compare

```
let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
        inputFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"

        dataArray = dataArray.sorted(by: { (crm1 : CRM, crm2 : CRM) -> Bool in
             inputFormatter.date(from: crm1.date1!)!.timeIntervalSinceNow <= inputFormatter.date(from: crm2.date1!)!.timeIntervalSinceNow
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Leo Dabus pointed out an article [SOLUTION POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541879/swift-3-ambiguous-use-of-operator-when-comparing-two-dates/39541975#39541975)

I used >= to correct the problem.

Comment: You can use any comparison operator. Just remove all custom operators you had previously defined for NSDate

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by force unwraping the date objects

```
let secondF = DateFormatter()
secondF.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let startdate = secondF.date(from: "2020-03-01")
let endDate = secondF.date(from: "2020-02-01")

if startdate! == endDate!{
   print("succedded")
}
```